# how do you handle error while using xui's xhr?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, xui

I'm using the following code to get some data from an external website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    xui.ready(function() { 

             var url = 'http://www.domain.com/getData.aspx';
             x$().xhr(url,function(){
                 alert(this.responseText);
             });    
        }
    );
</script>
```

**UPDATED:**

I updated my code to the following but even if I get a 404, the callback function still fired and not the error function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    xui.ready(function() { 

             var url = 'http://localhost:49617/SalesForceWebservice/Test/Default4.aspx';
             x$().xhr(url,{
                 method: 'get',
                 async: true,
                 error: function(){
                     alert('error');
                 },
                 callback: function(){
                     alert('success');
                 }
             });
        }
    );

</script>
```

The above code work just fine but this morning, the external website was down and this was causing the page to fail.  Based on the documentation, it looks like the callback function is called only when the xhr called received status 200. What is the best way to handle error 500 or 404?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the [documentation](http://xuijs.com/docs/xhr) ?

Take a look at the {options} you can pass as an argument:

> **method** String can be get, put, delete, post. default is get.
>
> **async** Boolean enables an asynchronous request. defaults to false.
>
> **data** String is a url encoded string of parameters to send.
>
> ***error** Function is called on error or status that is not 200. (i.e. failure callback).*
>
> **callback** Function is called on status 200 (i.e. success callback).

Comment: You'r welcome. Too bad i can't accept my own answer, can you do it for me? :p

Comment: I updated the question based on the documentation and added error to the options.  It seems to still fire the callback instead of the error.  The url that I put in there return 404 since the page doesn't exist

Comment: The error() function is triggered when the response starts with "45".. Have a look at https://github.com/xui/xui/blob/master/src/js/xhr.js (line 130) >> if((/^[45]/).test(req.status)) req.handleError();